# Windows Docker MSSQL with SSIS and MS-Access connectivity

Tags: sql-server, docker, ms-access, ssis

I am trying to create a Dockerfile (must be **Windows containers**) to run MS SQLSERVER with SSIS and connectivity to MS-Access. The images on Dockerhub do not include either.  NOTE: I am a noob to Docker and can find very little help for non-linux Dockers. So,

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer
```

or, is it

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.7.2
```

...

```
COPY Jet40SP8_9xNT.exe c:`\
```

And where do I get SSIS from?

Comment: You don't on Express.  SSIS is on SQL Server Standard and above.

Comment: Okay, I've changed it to developer version - same as Standard. I tried that before and it isn't in that Docker image, either.  Thanks.

Comment: No, Developer is the same as Enterprise, not Standard. Don't forget, however, that Developer **cannot** be used in production environments. The fact that you installed Express initially suggests this is a production environment, so you should not be using Developer.

Comment: Okay, I'll fix that to Standard.  It still doesn't alter the problem that NO Docker images on Dockerhub contain either SSIS or the MS Access oledb drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I have just come across this series of blog posts from 2018

https://andyleonard.blog/2018/12/ssis-docker-and-windows-containers-part-0-getting-started/

It looks like it will solve the SSIS portion of your question, but I do not know if it will solve the MS Access problem